# Skip specific lines in vim line numbering

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there any means to skip lines matching a pattern in vim's line numbering. This would be useful to number lines in output of the diff command as the numbers could then be brought to match the line numbers in one of the diff input files.

The matched number should not get a number and counting should continue with the next line which does not match the pattern.

Comment: What are you doing exactly?  eg, why not use vimdiff?  Or pipe diff to a simple awk script that adds line numbers?

Comment: After editing longer pieces of code, I sometimes print these parts (yes, on paper) to gain an overview whether the changes I made will be ok. I do this in addition to debugging and rather often I spot errors this way. I print syntax highlighted code in small font on large paper with line numbers. To highlight changes, I do e.g. something like `svn diff --diff-cmd diff -x -uwU9999999999 -r $start:HEAD $file` with `svn`. Of course line numbers in the print won't match anymore the original file and it can be a bit harder to find the matching line in the code. I am aware of vimdiff.

Comment: It would be great if I could ignore the old lines (which start with `-`), added by diff, in the counting, as well as the headings. The line numbers should then already match.